# Trouble getting the value of global 'camera' variable in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I have a THREE.js camera object included in my scene as such:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 6;
camera.position.y = 6;
```

and it works great.

I'm trying to obtain the camera.position.y property in real time as the user interacts with the scene.

```
var milkyWay = document.getElementById("chap3content");

var trackAngle = function() {
    var camAngle = window.camera.position.y;
    console.log(camAngle);
    return camAngle;
}


milkyWay.onmousedown = function() { 
  console.log("mouse pressed");
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", trackAngle);
  if (camAngle <= 0.25) {
      console.log("SHOW ME THE MONEY");
    }
}

milkyWay.onmouseup = function() {   
    console.log("mouse released");
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", trackAngle);
}
```

The function above works as expected and prints the value of camera.position.y into the console log every time the mouse is down and moved across the scene. The issue I am having is the the moment I reference the camAngle variable in the 'if' conditional, console log throws an error saying that camAngle cannot be found.

What gives? I've been trying to solve this for a very long time and have grown frustrated. I need the value of camera.position.y to have something else appear on the DOM for the user to interact with. Changing to window.camera.position.y makes no difference either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `camAngle` is out of scope for `milkyWay.onmousedown`

This is standard javascript concept that you can learn about with a search of post like [this one](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/).

The simplest solution for you here is to lift `camAngle` to the global scope. Just have:

```
var camAngle;
```

at the top of the script and don't redeclare it in functions.

Comment: Hey @user01! Thanks for the answer. I am aware of scoping and global variables and such. However, defining the variable outside the function just ends up giving me an error as well.

I found that the fix to the problem would be to declare the variable each time I need it in the functions. It's less than ideal but helps me get this done. It's still strange to me why the variable cannot be defined.

Comment: That works because javascript allows a declared but undefined variable in the comparison (which camAngle will be until it's set outside of your mousedown function). someUndefinedVariable < 0.25 will always evaluate to false, but it won't throw an exception. A few frames just roll with it undefined, get false, and nothing is logged to the console. Then you get real data and it works. To do this right  you should pass the variable as a parameter or define it properly as a global. Without seeing all of your code I can't be more specific, but what you posted does not properly scope camAngle.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thank you so much for helping me clarify this. You were of great help! :)